# Does $(Ha)*(Hb):=Ha^mb^n$ define a group operation in $G/H:=\{Ha, a\in G\}$ if and only if $H\unlhd G$ and $m=n=1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Claim**.

Let $G$ be a group, $H\le G$ and $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then:

$$(Ha)*(Hb):=Ha^mb^n\tag 1$$

defines a group operation in $G/H:=\{Ha, a\in G\}$ if and only if $H\unlhd G$ and $m=n=1$.

Right-to-left implication is well known. About the reverse implication, I think I managed to prove that "$*$" isn't a group operation for the particular cases $(m,n)=(-1,1),(1,-1)$, due to lack of associativity (unless $[G:H]=2$). What about other pairs $(m,n)\ne(1,1)$, namely: does the claim hold?

Comment: Could we not choose $n=r+1$ and $m=r+1$ for a group $G$ of order $r$. Because $a^{r+1}=a$?

Comment: @ André Armatowski  Let's assume $G$ possibly infinite.